# Cmake project in visual studio can't find standard libraries anymore

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, std

**Update 1**: I started a new project which made the error return, as well as create one additional error:

```
C1034: iostream: no include path set
```

**Update 2**: I managed to solve the problem by including the following in my top-level CMakeList

```
if(WIN32)
    include_directories(
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\include"
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\ucrt"
    )
    link_directories(
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.19041.0\\um\\x64"
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\lib\\onecore\\x64"
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.19041.0\\ucrt\\x64"
    )
endif()
```

I don't want to mark this as a solution yet, though. As I find it completely unacceptable that all this extra scouring is neccecary to get a project working in a program that should really be an install-and-get-going kind of affair and wish to find either a better solution than copying this snippet into all of my projects or the actual issue.

---

I installed VS2019 yesterday and compiled a little test program that just writes a number to the console.

Here's the content of my main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // Included to test whether including other libs did work.

#include "Graphics/window.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Width: "  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Height: " << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It worked just fine yesterday, but when I opened the project after including GLFW it stopped being able to find the iostream library and shows the following error:

```
Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "endl"    Slash.exe (source\Slash.exe) - x64-Debug    C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\source\main.cpp   9   
Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "endl"    Slash.exe (source\Slash.exe) - x64-Debug    C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\source\main.cpp   10  
Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "cout"    Slash.exe (source\Slash.exe) - x64-Debug    C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\source\main.cpp   9   
Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "cout"    Slash.exe (source\Slash.exe) - x64-Debug    C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\source\main.cpp   10  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "iostream"  Slash.exe (source\Slash.exe) - x64-Debug    C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\source\main.cpp   1   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "iomanip"   Slash.exe (source\Slash.exe) - x64-Debug    C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\source\main.cpp   2   
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\out\build\x64-Debug\CMakeProject1 C:\Users\Daisy\source\repos\CMakeProject1\out\source\main.cpp   1
```

Here's the relevant CMake files

Project root

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.19)

project(Slash)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_subdirectory(source)
```

Project root/source

```
add_subdirectory(Graphics)

add_executable (${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
PUBLIC
    Graphics/include
)

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    Graphics
)
```

Project root/source/Graphics

```
add_library(Graphics
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/window.cpp
)

target_include_directories(Graphics
PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/Graphics
)
```

I've also tried not including GLFW again, but that doens't help either.
(In case it matters: I incldue GLFW by using the CMAKE file that comes with it and using the add_subdirectory() command.)

I've looked into manually including the standard libraries manually, but I can't find them anywhere on my machine. And I just find it very weird that CMake just isn't able to locate the files anymore.

I've also tried including other standard libraries with the samae results to make sure it wasn't just iostream giving me trouble.

I'm using the stock C++ desktop workload with all default components selected in case that could be a problem.

I've had a simmilar issue before while trying to set up my C++ tools on Windows with differnet compilers and build systems, so I *think* this is just related to CMake.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: "In case it matters: I incldue GLFW by using the CMAKE file that comes with it and using ..." - Do not *describe* the code. Instead, **add the code** itself (`CMakeLists.txt`) into the question post. Also, replace the image of your code (C++ one) with the **textual** representation of the code. The same is about error messages. Note, that Stack Overflow discourages using images for code and error messages. See also [ask].

Comment: The error message appears to be a problem with your windows SDK.

Comment: Fair point. I've been stuck on this for a while and this combined with my failing mousepad that wouldn't let me select text caused me to skip over the proper formatting for a bit.

I've updated the question as suggested.

Comment: I also checked the Windows SDK. The currently installed version is "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)".
It's the one the VS installer selects by default.

Comment: I'm sad to say that after a reboot it suddenly decided to start working again without me having made any changes to my pc or the project. I was hoping to have more substantial solution than "just reboot and hope for the best."

Comment: `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)`... woah. Don't write to your _source_ directory. Use `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` instead

Comment: I wish somebody could explain to me why they write `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}` instead of... the project name, `Slash` here. Writing `Slash` is less typing, easier to read, easier to grep/search for, and won't change if your project is included by another (`CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` is the _top-level_ project). Moreover, the target name and the project name rarely change together. If you change the project name, you often _can't_ change the target name if someone else is including your build via `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: Honestly, I can't say why either. Those things are just habits I picked up from tutorials and other code. I also thought it was weird to write the binary to the SOURCE_DIR but that's what I came across when looking things up. Thanks for the input. I'm always trying to improve, so it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an appropriate answer that I just discovered this morning that I think may explain your dilemma:

> Per [**Microsoft's
> documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160),
> you cannot open a CMake project from the open recent dialog that pops
> up when Visual Studio starts, or, for some stupid reason, the CMake
> file isn't read correctly.  You need to open a CMake project from
> **File | Open | CMake...**, then browse to the root directory of the project and select the CMake file to open.

I understand this isn't a satisfying answer, but this is the only one I found that explains why a Cmake project worked one time and didn't work the next time.  The link above also describes how to create a CMake project "the Microsoft way", which I also understand and agree is equally distasteful.

Sorry friend.